# Extending external type declarations in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, antd

I am using Typescript and ant design library and I'm trying to extend one of the interfaces, only to add single property. 
I can import the original interface (so you know the folder structure):

`import { CollapseProps } from 'antd/lib/collapse/Collapse';`

I don't know however how to extend it.

I have created a `typings/antd` folder in project root, added paths configuration to `tsconfig.json` (and `baseUrl`):

```
"paths": {
  "antd": [
    "node_modules/antd",
    "typings/antd"
   ]
 }
```

And I tried different variants of exporting extended interfaces like:

```
export interface CollapsePanelProps {
  showArrow?: boolean;
}
```

in `typings/antd/index.d.ts`

or I tried to mimic the antd folder structure and put the `Collapse.d.ts` file inside `typings/antd/collapse`

or tried declaring namespace antd in my typings file and putting interface inside.

None of this seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that declaration files are only really for external Javascript files.

Would you be able to just extend the original interface and use your interface in your code?

```
import {CollapsePanelProps as OriginalCollapsePanelProps} from 'antd/Collapse';

export interface CollapsePanelProps extends OriginalCollapsePanelProps {
  showArrow?: boolean;
}
```

Comment: yes, I can do that (in fact - I don't think extend is even needed, as I understand merging I can just add this prop) but the problem is I am not using this interface directly. I am using Collapse.Panel component which is defined as a react component using this interface. As soon as I add `showArrow` on it, typescript will complain. So I'm looking for a way to tell Typescript to use my extended version inside ant, so to speak.

Comment: I think merging only applies to declarations (d.ts files) and not these sorts of interfaces

Comment: hmm but this interface originally is created in d.ts file and I want to extend it also in d.ts file